# Highlighting columns if text present

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

In Google Sheets, I would like to highlight certain parts of column whenever text is present. For example:

```
    A     B     C
1   foo         bar
2        ping
3   ----------------
4
5
6
```

In the above example, search for text between A1 and C2. If any text present, highlight column between A4 and C6. Here, I would like to get A4:A6 and C4:C6 highlighted.

How do I do this through conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example add a custom formula in conditional formatting and type in

```
=istext(a$1)
```

edit:

To have either row trip the trigger, use the "or" command in the conditional formatting custom function

```
=or(istext(a$1),istext(a$2))
```

To require both to trip it, use the "and"

```
=and(istext(a$1),istext(a$2))
```

Comment: It works fine when the text is present in the first row. If its present in the second row, it doesn't work. Updated the example.

Comment: Do you want A4:A6 to highlight if either row has text, or just certain cells?

Comment: Yes A4:A6 highlighted if either row has text. Its the same for other cells.

Comment: Thank you! I found another option to cover range of cells =sumproduct(istext(a$1:a$2)*1)